spectral gnn forward pass
Following the article: A Practical Guide to Graph Neural Networks: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.05234
Suppose our graph has $N$ nodes and Laplacian $L = UDU^T$. Let $\Theta$ denote a filter. Let $f_{k}$ denote the number of graph signals (or hidden channels) in the k:th layer. Let $H^{k}_{j,i}$ be the value in the $i$:th graph signal at the $j$:th vertex in the $k$:th layer. Then the authors say that we are calculating the $j$:th hidden channel for each vertex in the $k$:th hidden layer by (equation 5)
$$H^{k}_{j,:} = \sigma\left(\sum_{i=1}^{f_{k-1}} U \left(\Theta^{k}\left(U^{T}H^{k-1}_{:,i}\right)\right)\right) \quad j = 1,\dots, f_{k}$$
However, I don't see how this make sense from a dimension standpoint nor where the $j$ comes into play on the right hand side.
In particular, the first index is for the vertex and the second for the signal so should it not be $H^{k}_{:,j}$ on the left hand side? Secondly, what differs the $j$:th from the $j+1$:st element on the right hand side, is it suppose to be $\Theta^{k}_{j}$?
